# Meaning of Capitalization in Y/N Prompts

Tags: dialog, options

This issue came while running a script that requires a `yes` or `no` response before proceeding. Does the capitalization of the `y` and `n` usually matter?

In this example...

```
$copy_package some_package
File X is missing...
Do you want to continue ? (y/N)
```

I, as a user, expect that `N` is the recommended answer since it's capitalized (and because a file is `missing`), and `y` is not recommended since it's lower-case.

Note - This question isn't about what this *actually* means in regards the code, but whether or not the act of capitalization itself in this manner intentionally acts as a recommendation for which option to take.

Comment: As it stands, this question should better be moved to http://unix.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I think this belongs on ux.se. The question title relates to a UX issue. I'll amend the wording so that it removes some of the confusion, but as a concept it is *'does capitalizing a letter act as a recommended option'*. With scripting you have such a limited UI that there's not much else you *can* do to give emphasis to elements.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Usually the option in capitals is the default. The default will be used if `Enter` is pressed.